# webscrape and splitting of retrieved data into different lines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect the event date, time and venue. They came out successfully but then it is not reader friendly. How do I get the date, time and venue to appear separately like:

```
- event
  Date:
  Time:
  Venue:

- event
  Date:
  Time:
  Venue:
```

I was thinking of splitting but I ended up with lots of [ ] which made it looked even uglier. I thought of stripping but my regular expression but it does not appear to do anything. Any suggestions?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url_toscrape = "https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)
info_type = response.info()
responseData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, 'lxml')

events_absFirst = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title_first"})
date_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_date"})
events_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title"})

for first in events_absFirst:
    print('-',first.text.strip())
    print (' ',date)

for tr in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"ntu_event_detail"}):
    date_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_date"})
    events_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title"})

    for events in events_absAll:
        events = events.text.strip()
    for date in date_absAll:
        date = date.text.strip('^Time.*')
    print ('-',events)
    print (' ',date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the `div`s containing the event information, store the results, and then print each:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx').text, 'html.parser')
results = [[getattr(i.find('div', {'class':re.compile('ntu_event_summary_title_first|ntu_event_summary_title')}), 'text', 'N/A'), getattr(i.find('div', {'class':'ntu_event_summary_detail'}), 'text', 'N/A')] for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'ntu_event_articles'})]
new_results = [[a, re.findall('Date : .*?(?=\sTime)|Time : .*?(?=Venue)|Time : .*?(?=$)|Venue: [\w\W]+', b)] for a, b in results]
print('\n\n'.join('-{}\n{}'.format(a, '\n'.join(f'  {h}:{i}' for h, i in zip(['Date', 'Time', 'Venue'], b))) for a, b in new_results))
```

Output:

```
-​​7th ASEF Rectors' Conference and Students' Forum (ARC7)
 Date:Date : 29 Nov 2018  to 14 May 2019
 Time:Time : 9:00am to 5:00pm

-​Be a Youth Corps Leader
 Date:Date : 1 Dec 2018  to 31 Mar 2019
 Time:Time : 9:00am to 5:00pm

-​NIE Visiting Artist Programme January 2019
 Date:Date : 14 Jan 2019  to 11 Apr 2019
 Time:Time : 9:00am to 8:00pm
 Venue:Venue: NIE Art gallery

-​Exercise Classes for You: Healthy Campus@NTU
 Date:Date : 21 Jan 2019  to 18 Apr 2019
 Time:Time : 6:00pm to 7:00pm
 Venue:Venue: The Wave @ Sports & Recreation Centre

-​[eLearning Course] Information & Media Literacy (From January 2019)
 Date:Date : 23 Jan 2019  to 31 May 2019
 Time:Time : 9:00am to 5:00pm
 Venue:Venue: NTULearn
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use requests and test the length of stripped_strings

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url_toscrape = "https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx"
response = requests.get(url_toscrape)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

events = [item.text for item in soup.select("[class^='ntu_event_summary_title']")]
data =  soup.select('.ntu_event_summary_date')
dates = []
times = []
venues = []

for item in  data:
        strings = [string for string in item.stripped_strings]
        if len(strings) == 3:
            dates.append(strings[0])
            times.append(strings[1])
            venues.append(strings[2])    
        elif len(strings) == 2:
            dates.append(strings[0])
            times.append(strings[1])
            venues.append('N/A')    
        elif len(strings) == 1:
            dates.append(strings[0])
            times.append('N/A')
            venues.append('N/A')   

results = list(zip(events, dates, times, venues))
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

Comment: Did you try this?